# run a perl script on loading html page

Tags: javascript, html, perl

How to run a perl script on loading html page on the browser. i have tried to run the perlscript onload() and even by writing it on the head. but did not work
 perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI ':standard';
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

my $result="sakshi";

open(OUT,'>/var/cgi-bin/sample.html');
print 
 OUT header(),
start_html(
    -title   => 'Command',
  -text    => '#520063'
);
print OUT "Hello $result";
print OUT end_html();
close(OUT);
```

things i have tried in html:

1.

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="common_info.pl"></script>
</head>
```

2.

```
<body onload=call_perl()">
<script text/javascript>
function call_perl(){
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest;
ajax.open("GET", "http://localhost/cgi-bin/myscript.pl", true);
ajax.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The posted code does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML-file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/cgi-bin/my_script.pl"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

In my_script.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI ':standard';
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

my $result="sakshi";

open(OUT, ">", "/var/www/cgi-bin/sample.html") or die "cannot open > /var/www/cgi-bin/sample.html: $!";
print OUT header();
print OUT start_html(-title=>'Command',-text=>'#520063');
print OUT print("Hello $result");
print OUT end_html();
close(OUT);
```

When I activate the HTML file, the /var/www/cgi-bin/sample.html file will now contain generated content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Command</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body text="#520063">
1
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this clears it up abit

Comment: Yes, it does work, but it depends on what you actually wan't to happend?
Or do you get an Internal Server error? If so, post the error message from the error log.